# Modelling pillow with cloth simulation model floating

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

So I'm trying to model a pillow with the cloth simulation in blender 2.8. When I try to simulate the model I can see its forming the shape but eventually it starts to float or falls down. I set the Gravity to 0 in the Field weights and enabled object collision but it seems that my model doesn't stay in place. Also is there a way to have a seam to my pillow or do I also have to model it? Any suggestions will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Use the simulation up to the frame where you have the desired shape. Then you have two choices: 1.- Apply the modifier (read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/how-to-freeze-a-cloth-animation-at-x-frame) or 2.- Create a shapekey (read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63419/is-there-a-way-to-freeze-a-cloth-with-a-shape-key)

Comment: I know how to apply the cloth modifier so its stays the shape but how do you make it not to fall down or float that's my question.

Comment: Once you apply modifier to get the shape the object will not move anymore.

Comment: Nevermind I will figure it out thanks

Comment: Please comment on what happens when you apply the modifier or why it doesn't work for you. Are you using any other modifiers (soft body or rigid body?)

Comment: When I apply the modifier it will do what you expect to do, it will freeze the model. But dont worry about it I think I figure out how to make my model stay in place while it simulates the pillow. I was following a tutorial on youtube but I did it in a different way and it worked lol. My model will stay in place and I can apply the modifier with no issues.

Comment: Cloth modifier uses physics to work. You can prevent some vertices from moving by pinning them. Whatever is not pinned will fall. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49190/making-an-elastic-waistband-on-clothing?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75952/create-a-sail-with-cloth-and-curves-acting-as-softbodies

Comment: If you found an answer please share it, write it on the answers section so that other users with a similar question can learn from your experience. Read:

[Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, for the newbies like me having the same issues having the model falling or floating when trying to use the clothing modifier/physics don't use a force field. If you have watched the tutorials on Youtube they always say to insert a force field in the middle of the model that has the clothing physics but in 2.8 you don't have to. I don't know if its the same case with 2.79b. Maybe I was doing it wrong but in 2.8 you only have to play around with the clothing physics settings and values. I tried without the forcefield and my model doesn't move anymore LOL. So the only settings I enable and play around are STIFFNESS and SHAPE.

[image]

I enable the SEWING option so my model gets sewn in the middle. The magic happens underneath STIFFNESS. I don't really know exactly how it works but changing these values will make the object you are trying to model have different forms. I can't give exact numbers because it always gives a different form when you change the values. The settings I play around the most are TENSION, COMPRESSION and BENDING.You can play around with SHEAR but for me changing the value to a lower or higher number will cause my model to like implode or something. BUT you have to keep TENSION and COMPRESSION to closer values or it will cause the same thing as SHEAR does. Like I said I was playing with these values so I don't know if Im right lol

These values that you input will go hand to hand with the subdivisions applied on the object. So playing around with subdivisions and the settings will give you different forms. IF you think the results of the form of your model looks boring you can always edit some of the faces by dragging the points with PROPORTIONAL SCALING with SMOOTH enabled.

Here are the cushions I modeled:

[image]

After applying the clothing modifier I use PROPORTIONAL EDITING with SMOOTHING to get closer to the shape I wanted. Maybe you guys can use the same thing. I'm pretty sure experienced people might know an easier way... Sculpting is a good option but I wanted to  learn how to use the clothing physics.

The only thing I would say is play around and have fun. You never know what you might discover. I hope this is helpful to someone out there and if you recommend another way please let me know!